# Data not getting updated in array of objects when the value in scope variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects which is created on a button click. Now I have a scope variable that is assigned a default value.

This scope variable is part of textbox so now when user updates the textbox value that value is not getting automatically updated in all the records in `bonus` property of `$scope.job.referrals`records.

**Code:**

```
$scope.job.defaultBonus = 65;
function addNewReferrals{
  $scope.job.referrals.push({
                           id: null,
                           bonus: $scope.job.defaultBonus
                        });
}
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how do I update all `bonus` property in `$scope.job.referrals` when the `$scope.job.defaultBonus` gets change?

Comment: do you want to update all records in $scope.job.referrals and set each one to have a bonus property that is $scope.job.defaultBonus?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes, thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening for a change from an input field. You need `ng-model` and `ng-change`. `ng-model` binds the input value to the scope object.

```
<input ng-model='job.defaultBonus' ng-change='addNewReferrals()' />
```

You can iterate the array with `map()` and use the `{...}` spread operator to update the record.

```
function addNewReferrals() {
      $scope.job.referrals = $scope.job.referrals.map(el => ({ ...el,
        bonus: $scope.job.defaultBonus
      }))
    }
```

I set up an object called `$scope` for this snippet to demonstrate, but you would just use the angular property `$scope`.

```js
const $scope = {
  job: {
    defaultBonus: 0,
    referrals: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Fred"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Mary"
      }
    ]
  }
}

$scope.job.defaultBonus = 65;

function addNewReferrals() {
  $scope.job.referrals = $scope.job.referrals.map(el => ({ ...el,
    bonus: $scope.job.defaultBonus
  }))
}

addNewReferrals();

console.log($scope);
```

Comment: But the question is how do I know when the value of  $scope.job.defaultBonus is changed? that's the issue. When do I call the code to update the $scope.job.referrals for the newly changed $scope.job.defaultBonus?

Comment: So I have to call the ng-change event purposely to update the $scope.job.referrals. I was sort of avoiding it because I think angularjs scope variable changes should automatically updates the value but I guess it doesn't work for Array of objects.

Comment: Well, it does automatically update the $scope.job.defaultBonus value. That is automatic by virtue of ng-model. I thought you ALSO wanted to update the referrals array items with the value, in which case the explicit `ng-change` function is there.

Comment: If there's no calculation involved, then instead of updating the $scope.job.referrals array item by item, you could just always reference $scope.job.defaultBonus ... I wasn't sure what your use case was

Comment: I have to update the referrals because that array is passed to an API which then updates the value in database. What do you think about using $watch in this case?

Comment: I will still upvote your answer for your kind efforts towards helping me :)

Comment: why `$watch`? I don't understand - `ng-change` will do that for you.  Is the value of that input likely to get changed by anything other than a person typing it in? Your question said a user is typing something into a text box and you want the referrals array to get updated with that value. Am I misunderstanding something? Did we not want to bind the textfield to the defaultValue? Let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233635/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-kinglish).